# Python: Number Guessing Game

Tags: python, function

Your program chooses the number to be guessed by selecting an integer at random in the range 1 to 1000 (inclusive). If the player's guess is incorrect, your program should loop until the player finally gets the number right.  Your program should keep telling the player Too high or Too low to help the player “zero in” on the correct answer.  After a game ends, the program should prompt the user to enter "y" to play again or "n" to exit the game.

My problem is how do you generate a new random integer each time they want to play again?

Here's my code.

```
import random

randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 1000)

def main():
    print ""
    number = input("I have a number between 1 and 1000. Can you guess my number? Please type your first guess: ")
    guess(number)

def guess(number1):
    correct = False
    while not correct:
        if number1 > randomNumber:
            print "Too high. Try again."
            print ""
        elif number1 < randomNumber:
            print "Too low. Try again."
            print ""
        elif number1 == randomNumber:
           break
        number1 = input ("What number do you guess? ")
    if number1 == randomNumber:
       playAagain = raw_input ("Excellent! You guessed the number! Would you like to play again (y or n)? ")
       if playAagain == "y":
            main()

main()
```

Comment: You might want to consider not calling the `main` function inside of the `guess` function. This is called recursion (since it is the `main` function that called the `guess` function) and can cause your program to crash. Figure out how to replace it with a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Take this line:

```
randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 1000)
```

and place it inside `guess`:

```
import random

def main():
    print ""
    number = input("I have a number between 1 and 1000. Can you guess my number? Please type your first guess: ")
    guess(number)

def guess(number1):
    #########################################
    randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    #########################################
    correct = False
    while not correct:
        if number1 > randomNumber:
            print "Too high. Try again."
            print ""
        elif number1 < randomNumber:
            print "Too low. Try again."
            print ""
        elif number1 == randomNumber:
           break
        number1 = input ("What number do you guess? ")
    if number1 == randomNumber:
       playAagain = raw_input ("Excellent! You guessed the number! Would you like to play again (y or n)? ")
       if playAagain == "y":
            main()

main()
```

Now, a new random integer will be created each time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Put a loop in `main()` and initialize `randomNumber` at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

please try this remove four spaces starting from random to starting of while loop

```
import random

print " welcome to game of guessing "
print "you have 6 attempts"
num1 = random.randint(1,100)
print num1  # this is your computer generated number ( skip while running :only for test purpose)
num2 = num1+random.randint(1,15)
print " hint: number is close to " + str(num2)

count=1
```

while count<=6:
    print " enter the number you think"
    inputnum=raw_input()
    if inputnum==str(num1):
        print "congrats you guess the correct number"
        break

```
elif inputnum<str(num1):
    print " number is lower than correct one "
    count=count+1
elif inputnum>str(num1):
    print "number is greater than correct one"
    count=count+1
else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define your main() function like this.

```
def main():

    global randomNumber
    print ""
    randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    number = input("I have a number between 1 and 1000. Can you guess my number? Please type your first guess: ")
    guess(number)
```

And everything will be perfect. Hope this helps.